# is there any api for ending the scroll in pywinauto for gui automation using pywinauto in python

Tags: python, automation, pywinauto

I am trying to find all the list items in listbox and i tried to get all the list elements using scrolling and i didnt find any api for ending the scroll in pywinauto

i tried my own logic to get the termination condition

```
def __get_all_items(lisInstance):
    items = listInstance.items()
    while True:
        listInstace.scroll("down", "page")
        result = listInstance.items()
        if list(set(result)-set(items)) == []:
            return items
        items = list(set(items + list(set(result)-set(items))))
```

but this doesnt seems to be working when i tested on the application
When i tried to print the length of the items list, i am getting only half of the list items that are actually available.

Comment: if there is scroll bar then you must be getting its control id's use them to click on up down button of scrolling bar.

Comment: yes but we should know when to end this click, i am asking for this api, is it provided in the pywinauto framework or we need to have our own logic to end this scroll or click?

Comment: its up to you how you want to use it, you have provided the amount of click as "page" so it will scroll till page ends, that too you have added in while loop, you can try other parameters of the `scroll` -https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.controls.hwndwrapper.html#pywinauto.controls.hwndwrapper.HwndWrapper.scroll  function